# only algorithm code 1 and 2 are supported

Tags: python, pypdf

I would like to read the pdf file. This is a book.pdf with a password (256 bit AES encryption). I know a password. I am using Jupyter Notebook.

I get an error:

```
import PyPDF2
reader = PyPDF2.PdfFileReader('book.pdf')
reader.decrypt('333')
reader.getPage(0)


---------------------------------------------------------------------------
 NotImplementedError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
 <ipython-input-12-7dd54b6a760a> in <module>()
  1 import PyPDF2
  2 reader = PyPDF2.PdfFileReader('book.pdf')
  ----> 3 reader.decrypt('333')
  4 reader.getPage(0)

 c:\users\a\programs\python\python36-32\lib\site-packages\PyPDF2\pdf.py in 
 decrypt(self, password)
 1985         self._override_encryption = True
 1986         try:
 -> 1987             return self._decrypt(password)
 1988         finally:
 1989             self._override_encryption = False

 c:\users\a\python\python36-32\lib\site-packages\PyPDF2\pdf.py in 
_decrypt(self, password)
1994             raise NotImplementedError("only Standard PDF encryption 
handler is available")
1995         if not (encrypt['/V'] in (1, 2)):
-> 1996             raise NotImplementedError("only algorithm code 1 and 2 
are supported")
1997         user_password, key = self._authenticateUserPassword(password)
1998         if user_password:

NotImplementedError: only algorithm code 1 and 2 are supported
```

Comment: https://github.com/mstamy2/PyPDF2/issues/53

Comment: https://github.com/mstamy2/PyPDF2/issues/378

Comment: Also see https://github.com/mstamy2/PyPDF2/issues/385 for status. Basically, PyPDF2 has been dead for 3 years; after half a year of discussion on resuming maintenance, it looks like the people involved have decided to abandon it and begin work on a [PyPDF3](https://github.com/mstamy2/PyPDF3) project, but little to nothing has been done on that yet. So, the answer is either (a) wait until PyPDF3 is ready for prime time (if ever), (b) switch to a different PDF library, or (c) use workarounds like subprocessing out to command-line tools for steps PyPDF2 can't handle, like decrypting algorithm 4.

Answer (score 7):

Recently, I also faced the same issue. I am not sure why the error occurs, but here is a way to mitigate it, using a different module than `PyPDF2` :

```
import pikepdf
pdf = pikepdf.open('book.pdf',password='333')
pdf.save('book_without_pass.pdf')
```

The above code save the encrypted pdf `book.pdf` with the password, `'333'` to `book_without_pass.pdf`

Comment: Also works for files that give this error, even though they are not password-protected.

Comment: Can it access the contents of `pdf` without having to first save it? I cant seem to be able to

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue, then changed PDF options on Encryption Level: 40 bit RC4
and it helped.
I think it relates with PyPDF2 module.

Answer (score 1):

`NotImplementedError` This is because module does not support the files encrypted format
You have to try different modules

Answer (score 1):

Meanwhile, the necessary functionality has been added in PyPDF2.

I tested it in version 3.0.1. If you arrived here via a search on the error message, you should check whether the latest PyPDF2 version fixes your problem.

For historical background, see the comment that [abarnert](https://stackoverflow.com/users/908494/abarnert) posted under the question.